# Do not show preference screen in fullscreen mode Android

Tags: java, android, preferences

I'm having an app, that shows a preference screen. Here is the layout of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:summary="Alarm sound"
        android:title="Select Sound">

        <RingtonePreference
            android:id="@+id/ringtone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:key="Alarm"
            android:ringtoneType="notification|alarm"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:summary="Alarm" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the activity is really simple:

```
package zabolotnii.pavel.timer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class SoundSelect extends PreferenceActivity{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.sound_select);

   }
}
```

You can see, that is only one item to be set. I tried different ways to show directly the Ringtone Preference without Preference category, or not show this screen in fullscreen, but nothing happened. Do you have any idea about how to make this screen look better and smaller?

Answer (score 0):

create res/layout/preference.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

change in your activity

```
  package zabolotnii.pavel.timer;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


  public class SoundSelect extends PreferenceActivity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.preference);  
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.sound_select);

  }
}
```